# How to set in parametr funciton a List of any types?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a function like this:

```
public static String getNumberOfItemsInList(Order[] orders) {
     return String.valueOf(objects.length);
}
```

I must use this function in many options:

```
getNumberOfItemsInList(list of ordres);
getNumberOfItemsInList(list of users);
getNumberOfItemsInList(list of services);
```

How to pass in the parameter of the function `List` that would take any type we give it? I don't want to create a function for any type of the list,
can somebody help me?

Comment: look about generic type <T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write 2 methods, so you're covered regarding the definition of "list":

```java
public static String getNumberOfItemsInList(Object[] array) {
     return String.valueOf(array.length);
}

public static String getNumberOfItemsInList(Collection<?> coll) {
     return String.valueOf(coll.size());
}
```

The first can handle all types of arrays, and the second can handle all types of collections, including all types of lists.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static <T>  String getLength(T[] items) {
    return String.valueOf(items.length);
}
```